# What is this flowering tree

Tags: identification

We have this tree that spontaneously planted itself  5 years or so ago. We decided to let it go and see what it is. Last year I noticed some tiny white flowers at the top of the tree. This year there are many more buds (haven’t opened yet) and I was able to get this picture of them. I live in upstate NY and this picture was taken May 5. What is this tree??[image][image][image][image]

Comment: It looks like an apple or pear tree. Can you take picture of its leaves?